# How do I count elements in a while loop and apply css class?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater from ACF and what I want to is loop and count the items and based on the counted items output a particular css class.

Can I get help so the output of css classes depends on the counted items. For example if there was six items the class would be col-6 etc...

```
<?php 
    if( have_rows('rainbow') ):

    $counter = 0;
    while( have_rows('rainbow') ): the_row();

        // vars
        $name = get_sub_field('name');
        $age = get_sub_field('age');
        $cssClass = 'col';

        for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {

            if($counter === 6) {
                $cssClass = 'col-lg-4';
            } elseif ($counter == 4) {
                $cssClass = 'col-xl-6';
            }
            else {
                $cssClass = 'col';
            }

        }

        echo '<div class=\'' . $cssClass. '\'>';
            echo "<h4>" . $name . "</h4>";
            echo "<p>" . $age . "</p>";

            echo $counter;

        echo '</div>';


        $counter++;

    endwhile;

endif; 
?>
```

Comment: why are you using for loop?

Comment: your question is still open, please close this by accepting the answer, this will help to future visitors

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why are you using `for` loop here, `$i < $counter` this condition cant be true because `$i` and `$counter` both of them started from 0. so `0 < 0 == FALSE`

You just need to remove `for` loop inside your `while` loop.

Or, if you are using `for` loop somewhere else in your code, then you can just move your conditions outside the `for` loop.

**Second Solution:**
Second, if you start `$counter` from 1 then you can achieve your desired result as given example:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$counter = 1;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $cssClass = 'col';
    for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {
        if($counter === 6) {
            $cssClass = 'col-lg-4';
        } elseif ($counter == 4) {
            $cssClass = 'col-xl-6';
        }
        else {
            $cssClass = 'col';
        }
    }
    echo $cssClass."<br/>";
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

**Result:**

```
col
col
col
col-xl-6
col
col-lg-4
```

Comment: @PaddyGriffin: glad to help u, dont forgot to accept the answer this will help to future visitors.

Comment: I thought this solved my issue, but when I used the code in another project  it didnt work as expected.

In the first project I had this code running in a template part file which was looped through from a foreach loop

In my real project I want to use the above code in template file but not inside of foreach and wondering what needs to happen to get the code to fire correctly.

Comment: @PaddyGriffin: you can change foreach part as u need

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$counter = 1;
while( have_rows('rainbow') ): the_row();
    // vars
    $name = get_sub_field('name');
    $age = get_sub_field('age');

    if ( $counter == 4 ) {
        $cssClass = 'col-xl-6';
    } elseif ( $counter == 6 ) {
        $cssClass = 'col-lg-4';
    } else {
        $cssClass = 'col';
    }

    echo '<div class="' . $cssClass . '">';
        echo "<h4>" . $name . "</h4>";
        echo "<p>" . $age . "</p>";
        echo $counter;
    echo '</div>';


    $counter++;

endwhile;
```

try this

Comment: thanks for this I updated the code,  i was expecting if the count was 4 the class col-xl-6 would be outputted but it outputs col instead.